# Is it possible to use conditional renderings with Sitecore MVC

Tags: mvc, presentation

I have problems using conditional renderings with MVC (on Sitecore 8.0 rev. 150121)

I've created a condition and assigned it to the controller rendering but this condition never gets called.

From what I see the conditions attached to the renderings are triggered in the `insertRenderings` pipeline which doesn't seem to be executed when we have an MVC layout.

Am I missing something or the conditional renderings are supported only with Web Forms? If so I am wondering is there a graceful way to make it work with MVC

Comment: where are you setting the condition? on the presentation of the item or a global condition?

Comment: In MVC renderings are customized via `mvc.customizeRendering` pipeline.
If you are talking about code you would need to provide additional implementation for MVC.

Comment: @RichardSeal I am setting the condition on the presentation details (under _Personalization_ section of rendering options)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Conditional renderings work fine with MVC. For version 8, you *must* have `Analytics.Enabled` set to true so you can get to the personalization section of the presentation.

"Global" conditional renderings *do not* work with MVC, so you need to stick to personalization of the rendering on the items presentation rather than a global rendering rule.

Here is how you set a Personalization rule. Edit the items presentation and then edit the Device you need. Most likely the `Default` one.

Select the rendering you want to personalize and click the `Personalize` button. If that button is not visible, Analytics is disabled:

[image: Edit the Presentation]

Then you can add a new condition:

[image: Add a condition]

You can click the edit button to edit the rule for your condition. Add as many variants as you need, you can hide component, change the Datasource etc...

Comment: Could you please point out which pipeline/processor is responsible for executing rendering conditions on MVC?

Answer (score 6):

The conditions you set under [Personalization section](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11/how-to-invoke-other-actions-in-conditional-renderings/18#18) are *Global Conditional Rendering Rules* and are not [supported in Sitecore MVC](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/mvc/mvc_rules_and_personalization).

> MVC does not support global conditional rendering rules (the rules that apply to all renderings).
>
> This means that when you use MVC, you cannot set up a system of global conditions that determine which content is displayed to website visitors who meet these conditions every time the rendering is called.

It *should* be possible to make them run by adding in some appropriate processors overrides in the correct MVC pipelines, but this is likely to have a solution wide performance impact since the rules would run for every single rendering. This is most likely the reason it was removed in the first place.

The global rules do however still work with WebForms only solutions.